# Запихнуть элемент динамического массива в scanf

Tags: c, функции, динамические-массивы, динамические-структуры, scanf

Никак не пойму - сколько и где * и & должно быть.

А точнее, как реализовать scanf и malloc.

```
// Структура, являющаяся элементами массива
struct token {
 unsigned int postindex;
 unsigned long long int bedeutung;
}

int main() {
// Переменные
 struct token *token_dynmass;

// Функция
 InputFiller(&token_dynmass);

 return 0;
}

char InputFiller(struct token **token_dynmass) {

// Инициализация структуры
 *token_dynmass = (struct token*)malloc(4*sizeof(struct token));
 *token_dynmass = (struct token*)realloc((*token_dynmass),(4*1.5*sizeof(struct token)));

// Считываем индекс (ключ)
 scanf("%u", token_dynmass[0]->bedeutung);
}
```

Проблема также состоит в том, что мне не просто нужно скормить функции дин. массив, но и сделать так, чтобы функция "меняла" его в main. Т.е. Чтоб после я мог, например, через printf вывести этот массив уже из main.

P.S. Знаю, что так не делают, но мне нужно разобраться с указателями.

P.P.S. *token_dynmass - динамический массив